# Changing suEXEC Path / CentOS 6

Tags: apache-httpd, suexec

I have recently installed httpd on a Centos 6 server. From what I see suEXEC was compiled with the values below;

```
 -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="apache"
 -D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/httpd/suexec.log"
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=500
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```

I was wondering if there's a way to change these values without compiling Apache from scratch?

Comment: As far as i know, recompile suexec/apache will be needed. However, you can use the rpm sources to make things easier.

Comment: Is this a self compiled version of apache or out of one of the yum repositories for CentOS 6?

Comment: it was the one from official CentOS repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to augment the options a tool was complied with so you're left to re-compile it yourself if you need additional options added in. With a package like httpd (Apache) on a RedHat based distro this isn't too bad.

You'll essentially need 3 things to do this:

1. dependencies installed for httpd
2. source RPM version of httpd
3. an rpmbuild area

#### dependencies

You can use the tool `yum-builddep` to help in the effort. This tool will download all the packages required to build & install a given RPM. So you'll need to get yourself a version of the httpd RPM. But make sure to get it's source version typically named src.rpm files. For example:

```
mypackage-1.0.0-1.src.rpm
```

#### source RPM

For CentOS 6.2 you could download this source RPM:
- http://vault.centos.org/6.2/os/Source/SPackages/httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.src.rpm

#### build environment

I typically use a tool to set this up for me, `rpmdev-setuptree`.

```
$ yum install rpmdevtools
$ rpmdev-setuptree
```

Now change directories to your newly built rpmbuild area, and install the source RPM so that we can begin to modify how it get's built:

```
$ cd ~/rpm
$ rpm -ivh httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.src.rpm
```

How we need to edit the `httpd.spec` file. This is the file that details how the eventual binary RPM should be constructed:

```
$ nano SPEC/httpd.spec
```

You'll need to find a section in this file where configure is being invoked. I usually search for the string `--prefix`. This next step is where you can add your modifications which will change how `suexec` get's built.

*excerpt of configure stanza from `httpd.spec`*

```
../configure \
        --prefix=%{_sysconfdir}/httpd \
        --exec-prefix=%{_prefix} \
        --bindir=%{_bindir} \
        --sbindir=%{_sbindir} \
        --mandir=%{_mandir} \
        --libdir=%{_libdir} \
        --sysconfdir=%{_sysconfdir}/httpd/conf \
        --includedir=%{_includedir}/httpd \
        --libexecdir=%{_libdir}/httpd/modules \
        --datadir=%{contentdir} \
        --with-installbuilddir=%{_libdir}/httpd/build \
        --with-mpm=$mpm \
        --with-apr=%{_prefix} --with-apr-util=%{_prefix} \
        --enable-suexec --with-suexec \
        --with-suexec-caller=%{suexec_caller} \
        --with-suexec-docroot=%{contentdir} \
        --with-suexec-logfile=%{_localstatedir}/log/httpd/suexec.log \
        --with-suexec-bin=%{_sbindir}/suexec \
        --with-suexec-uidmin=500 --with-suexec-gidmin=100 \
        --enable-pie \
        --with-pcre \
        $*
```

Save the file and now you're ready to build your version of httpd.

#### building source RPM

The following command will build your RPM:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba SPEC/httpd.spec
```

If all goes correctly you should be left with a new version of the RPM in the RPM directory here: `RPM/httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm`.

Now you can install it like any other normal RPM.

#### References

- [CentOS RPM Tutorial Part 1 - Building your own RPMs](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/164/centos-rpm-tutorial-1/)
- [Building Apache from Source As an RPM (Apache 2) - Apache](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Building-Apache-the-Way-You-Want-It/5/)
- [[one-liner]: Using yum-builddep to Speed Up the Building of SRPMs on Fedora & CentOS](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/8297/one-liner-using-yum-builddep-to-speed-up-the-building-of-srpms-on-fedora-centos/)